# Time cost difference between loading an image as gray scale and converting it to gray scale after loading it as color image, in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, resize, imread

I am trying to resize a grayscale image into its half size. There are two options:

1) Load it as gray scale directly by flag `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`; Or

2) Load it as color by flag `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` and then convert it to gray scale

However, I found the time cost is so different. The option 1) costs >100ms in resize but 2) only costs 1ms.

So why?

The code sample is as follows:

```
namespace utils
{
    inline double time() { return (double)clock() / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1e3; }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string fname = "./data/f0.jpg";
    Mat im = imread(fname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    //Mat im = imread(fname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    if (im.channels() == 3)
        cvtColor(im, im, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    double t0 = utils::time();
    resize(im, im, im.size() / 2, 0, 0, INTER_AREA);
    double t1 = utils::time();

    cout << t1 - t0 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the first case most likely the grayscale conversion is done by the image decoder library (e.g. libpng, libjpeg, ...).

Comment: The only reason I can think of for this behavior would be if the first method creates a discontinuous matrix. You can check with [`Mat::isContinuous`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa90cea495029c7d1ee0a41361ccecdf3)